# How to import another contract in geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, import

sir,

I have two contracts. I want to test the import statement in geth.
My first contract is names strtest.sol. The code is below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
import "global_functions.sol";
contract strtest
{
    bool ib_equal;
    function test(string p1,string p2) returns(bool) {
        ib_equal = strcompare(p1,p2) ;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Another contract is named  "global_functions.sol". The code is below:

```
function strcompare(string p_source,string p_target) external returns(bool) {
    bytes memory lbt_left;
    bytes memory lbt_right;            
    lbt_left = bytes(p_source);
    lbt_right = bytes(p_target);
    bool lb_equal = true;
    uint li_length = lbt_right.length;
    for( uint p = 0 ;p < li_length;p++){
        if (lbt_left[p] == lbt_right[p] ) {
            continue;
        } else {
            lb_equal = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return lb_equal;
}
```

My question is:
How to compiler strtest in geth? ( Not in Browser-Solidity)

Below is my test situation:

```
> var test1 = "pragma solidity ^0.4.2;import '/barkely/lend/global_functions.sol';contract strtest { bool ib_equal; function test(string p1,string p2) returns(bool) { return true;  }}"
undefined
> var test1Compiled = web3.eth.compile.solidity(test1)

Error: solc: exit status 1
/tmp/geth-compile-solidity119170518:1:24: Error: Source "/barkely/lend/global_functions.sol" not found: File not found.
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;import '/barkely/lend/global_functions.sol';contract strtest { bool ib_equal; function test(string p1,string p2) returns(bool) { return true;  }}
                       ^------------------------------------------^

    at web3.js:3119:20
    at web3.js:6023:15
    at web3.js:4995:36
    at <anonymous>:1:21

>
```

Now,
How I change the import path,ex:

```
import '/barkely/lend/global_functions.sol'  //absoulte path
```

or

```
import './global_functions.sol'  //the same path with strtest.sol
```

,it doesn't work.

So how should I do?

Thanks!
        Barkely

Answer (score 2):

use the second option it is easiest

```
import "./global_functions.sol" //the file should be in the current directory
```

where . represents the current and .. as the parent directory. please read more to understand how to import a file in the [official doc](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout-of-source-files.html).

Answer (score 2):

sir,

I use the second option,it doesn't work.
   The error message is below:

```
Error: solc: exit status 1
/tmp/geth-compile-solidity546755989:1:24: Error: Source "/tmp/str2.sol" not found: File not found.
```

So I copy the str2.sol to /tmp/str2.sol,then this program works. Client program can call the "test" function of "strtest" contract and the result is correct.

I will try it till find the solution. Any new result ,I will post to this.